# How to call a function from c++ to a widget blueprint in Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4

How can i call a c++ variable inside a blueprint. I have created a widget blueprint and i have to display a variable value in a text block inside that blueprint. The variable is obtained from c++. Is it possible.? Please help.....

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UPROPERTY](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Properties/index.html) macro to specify properties for the next variable you declare. In this case you may want to use the [BlueprintReadOnly](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Reference/Properties/Specifiers/BlueprintReadOnly/index.html) property.

So if your variable declaration looks like this:

```
int widgetValue
```

You have to add this:

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly)
int widgetValue
```

This will make the variable readable in blueprints but it won't allow you to modify it through those means.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I manage my Widgets in Unreal Using C++

You want to create a custom widget to base your widgets on. To do this create a C++ class that inherits from UUserWidget:

```
// Copyright 2014-2016 Blackbriar Softworks, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#pragma once

#include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"
#include "XUserWidget.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class UNSUNGHEROES_API UXUserWidget : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()


public:

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "XConfiguration")
    FString WidgetName;
};
```

Inside the editor you want to now reparent your widget that you want to have access to custom properties:

Open Widget -> File -> Reparent Widget -> Your C++ Widget Class Name

now you can access the WidgetName inside the blueprint widget or use data binding to display the values./

This is where you expose the property to blueprints:

**UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "XConfiguration")**
**FString WidgetName;**