# How to change value of text in a widget blueprint from c++

Tags: c++, widget, unreal-engine4

How to change value of text in a widget blueprint from `c++` in `Unreal Engine`?

Comment: Please add at least a snipped code.

Comment: Added extra tags and marked the concepts in the question. However, a trial code would be welcomed.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551229/how-to-call-a-function-from-c-to-a-widget-blueprint-in-unreal-engine/35652396#35652396

Answer (score 1):

First, create a class in C++, then set your blueprint's parent class to this class.
create an FString in your class and add: `UPROPERTY(Category = UserInterface, EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)` to it. In the blueprint, bind this variable to whatever text you what to change.

Then all you you have to do is update the variable from C++, and it will automatically change the text in your UI.